# Mostrar un dialogo en android

Tags: java, android, alertdialog

Tengo un problema:
Quiero mostrar un dialogo que hice a partir de un layout que tiene un texto y un botón pero no entiendo porque me dice que la aplicación se detuvo.

Codigo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    }

    public void b1(View view) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogo6, null);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(child);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

        Button dismissButton = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.boton);
        dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

El dialogo que quiero mostrar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="Alto Titulo Ameo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/titulo"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="340dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/imagen" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Descripcion del dialogo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/boton"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Agrega detalles del error de consola

Comment: añade el logcat

Comment: tu layout no tiene el id b1 asociado a ningún elemento, ni tiene un elemento del tipo button

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de tu metodo onCreate donde dice b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1); tenes que reemplazar por:

```
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton);
```

Dentro del metodo b1 donde dice  View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogo6, null); tenes que reemplazar por:

```
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
```

Los errores eran solo por el tema de las referencias a tu vista. Con esto se soluciona. Lo probé desde mi dispositivo Samsung S5

Answer (score 1):

Si no agregas el LogCat los problemas pueden ser varios, yo noto 2 cosas a verificar:

**1)** Dentro de tu layout activity_main.xml debes tener un Boton con id b1, asegura sea así, ya que este es el código que realiza lo que comento:

```
...
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
...
```

**2)** el método   `public void b1(View view) {` es llamado desde la vista en el layout, asegura este definido de esta forma:

```
<Button
 ...
 ... 
 android:onClick="b1" />
```

y **3)** revisa que dentro de tu layout `dialogo6.xml` tengas definido un botón con id `boton`:

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/boton
 ...
 ... />
```

el cual es usado aquí :

```
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogo6, null);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(child);

final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
...
Button dismissButton = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.boton);
```

Answer (score -1):

hay otra opción que es crear una **Activity**(en blanco) con lo que desees dentro y en el **Manifest** asignar el atributo

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"
```

**Cabe destacar que toda la actividad quedara en modo Dialog.** y no necesitas importar ninguna liberia de terceros ya que es parte de Android Studio. Saludos